# Slax boot error vesamenu.c32

Tags: boot, slackware

I followed the instructions in the Slax documentation to download the 64 bit Slax 7.0.8 ZIP, unzipped it onto an SD card, and ran bootinst.bat to make the card bootable.  This was done from a Slax liveCD session.  The progress messages indicated that everything was successfully completed.

When I boot from the SD card, I get a message early in the process: 
`failed to load com32 file /slax/boot/vesamenu.c32`, and the boot hangs (the file does exist).  I found some online links to other people with the same problem.  For example, [this one](http://old.slax.org/forum.php?action=view&parentID=84810).  However, I can't make any sense of the discussion.

Is anyone familiar with this problem and can describe how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll close the loop on this question since I was able to find information on the problem.  Apparently there is a version mismatch for the files in the boot folder.

According to [this post](http://old.slax.org/forum.php?action=view&parentID=87300) on a Slax forum, the solution is to copy a number of files from a working Linux system (I assume Slackware-based).  However, I could not locate those files on any version of Linux I have.

Another solution was suggested in [this post](http://old.slax.org/forum.php?action=view&parentID=86499) on the same forum.  That was to comment out a line in bootinst.sh.  I did not try that so I cannot confirm that it works.

I decided to use a different distro rather than to rely on one that does not appear ready for prime time.